# How to use indexifembedded tag with subpages in iframe

Tags: search-engine-indexing, tags, seo, google-search

Google released a new meta tag: `<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,indexifembedded" />`, this year. It allows to index content inside iFrame.
I'm trying to use it on our website and it seems to index some of the content from iFrame.

The issue is that iFrame that I use, has subpages, and I want these subpages to be indexed as well.
So my question is: is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by subpages? Do you mean nested iframes, or do you mean hyperlinks for the crawler to follow within the iframe?

Comment: Iframe has some subpages inside. So the page that we embedded. Inside there is, let's call it "main page" and some products that, when you click on some, you get to that specific product. Now I can see that the "mainpage" is indexed... that's a progress, but still no indexing of subpages/specific products

Comment: When you click on the product pages, it changes the URL, right?

Comment: Yeah, when I go on some specific product it has a different URL